# Jquery Selecting to hide and show issue: More than two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

recently trying to make working pages to show and hide each element according to button, but I am somehow missing something to make this work, or somehow it isnt working at all.

When i run this example, the first two "A" links work, but not the third, is there a way to actually seperate it to where each element shows singular while hiding the rest?

Here is my coding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">          </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("p").hide();          //to hide all P elem for user to start
                $("#hide").click(function(){
                    $("p#2").show();
                    $("p#1").hide();    //Yes i tried grouping by selectors
                    $("p#3").hide();    //and also seperating like this
                });                     //but both didnt work :(
                $("#show").click(function(){
                    $("p#1").show();
                    $("p#2").hide();
                    $("p#3").hide();
                });
                $("#other").click(function(){
                    $("p#3").show();
                    $("p#1").hide();
                    $("p#2").hide();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>please select a button to begin
        <br />
        <br />
        <p id="1">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
        <p id="2">If you click on the "Show" button, i will disappear!</p>
        <p id="3">yay, another one</p>

        <a id="hide">Hide</a>
        <a id="show">Show</a>
        <a id="third">other</a>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace this:

```
$("#other").click(function(){
```

With:

```
$("#third").click(function(){
```

Comment: yep, operator error.  But may i ask, is there a better way to efficiently write
'$blah.show(); $blah2.hide(); $blah3.hide();'?

Comment: @GarethCompton Give all the elements a class. Then use `$(".classname").hide(); $("#blah").show()`

Comment: tried it but it hid all, regardless of what i click

-edit- again operator error.  by class i thought each one had to be the same, but i didnt think of each individual to run hide smoothly

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
                $("p").hide();          
   //to hide all P elem for user to start
                $("#hide").click(function(){
                    $("p#2").show();
                    $("p#1").hide();    
                  //Yes i tried grouping by selectors
                    $("p#3").hide();    
                  //and also seperating like this
                });                     
   //but both didnt work :(
                $("#show").click(function(){
                    $("p#1").show();
                    $("p#2").hide();
                    $("p#3").hide();
                });
                $("#third").click(function(){
                  
                    $("p#3").show();
                    $("p#1").hide();
                    $("p#2").hide();
                });
            });
```

```html
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">          </script>
      
        <div>please select a button to begin
        <br />
        <br />
        <p id="1">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
        <p id="2">If you click on the "Show" button, i will disappear!</p>
        <p id="3">yay, another one</p>

        <a id="hide">Hide</a>
        <a id="show">Show</a>
        <a id="third">other</a>
    </div>
```